# Illegal else without matching if

Tags: c++

So I tried to build a simple calculator but I keep getting the same error "illegal else without matching if" after I put the second else I searched the other answer but none seems to help, I would be grateful if someone could give me any tips to fix this

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main() {

    int number_1;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> number_1;

    int number_2;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> number_2;

   int number_3 = number_1 + number_2;

   int number_4 = number_1 - number_2;

   int number_5 = number_1 * number_2;

   int number_6 = number_1 / number_2;

   if (number_1 + number_2) {

    cout << "" << number_3 << endl;
   }

   else {

    if (number_1 - number_2) {

        cout << "" << number_4 << endl;
    }
   }

   else {

    if (number_1 * number_2){ 
        cout << "" << number_5 << endl; 4
    }
         }


  else {

    if (number_1 / number_2) {

        cout << "" << number_6 << endl;
    }

   }

   cout << "Press enter to continue" << endl;
   cin.ignore(10, '\n');
   cin.get();


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `else { ` constructs should be `else if {` constructs.

Comment: Just check the number of `{` and `}` and you'll see that the second `else` has no matching `if`.

Comment: Get a C++ book please. You cannot have multiple else's to one if. You are looking for ````else if ````

Comment: indent your code with a predictable pattern and spotting stuff like this becomes... well not child's play, but a lot easier.

Comment: Off topic: When you find yourself making variable like `number_1`, `number_2`, `number_3`, etc... consider using an array: `int numbers[6];`

Comment: @user4581301 Baby steps...  Let's help the OP understand `if` statements first...  lol

Comment: First of all, please fix your formatting; you will be able to spot syntax errors much more easily this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see your direct question and the code that you supplied and I see the answers and comments that have already answered your question here are a few things to keep in mind first is a simple rule also applied with a style of doing it.

- **Rules of if... else if... else { } block statements.**

  - First statement starts with an if ( condition || a set of conditions ) that will either evaluate to true or false either by conditional Boolean comparison, or logical mathematical evaluation comparison

    - **Examples:**

      - Boolean:  `if ( something (x) is true or false )`
      - Logic  :  `If ( somevalue (x) is <, >, <=, >=, !=, == somevalue (y)or someFunction or operation done to either (x) or (y) or both )`
  - The next step is assigning the beginning of the block statement and this can slightly vary:

    - If and only if a single line of execution follows the if statement the opening and closing braces `{}` can be omitted and can be followed by an `if else( ... )` or an `else` statement.
    - If more than one line of code execution needs to be done with in the `scope` of these `block statements` then the opening and closing braces `{}` need to be present to define the enclosing block statement in order to define its scope. *If not sure look up `scope` and `block`: All blocks - a section of code that starts with `{` and ends with `}` has its own local scope.
  - Returns: - When these `if ... else if ... else` statements are found in a function that does not return a value, the only thing that should be called is the `return;` statement when the condition gives cause to return from that function; not all `if else if else` states will cause a function to terminate but many do, otherwise if that function does have a `return value` and the execution of some code block in the scope of an `if else if else` statement gives cause to return from that function then all blocks of that statement should then also return that functions data type or throw some type of error or exception.
- **Style**

  - Indentation and uses of opening and closing brackes `{}`
  - Spacing
  - Nested Loops

    ```
    // Here are a couple of different styles
    // Tip about indentation - single tab normally 4-5 white spaces
    // with 4 being most common sometimes 3, but very rare: 
    // I prefer 4. Which ever indent spacing you decide to choose 
    // make sure all of your code follows that convention.

    // Style 1a: Single Execution with omitted braces
    if ( some condition )  // Braces {} omitted    
        // single execution;  // Single Execution without any following 
                            // else if...else blocks
    // Next statement of execution that doesn't belong to the above if;

    // Style 1b: Single Execution with braces
    if ( some condition ) 
    {                       // Beginning Brace Started on separate line.
       // single execution;
    }            
    // next statement not belonging to if statement;

    // Style 1c: Single Execution with braces
    if ( some condition ) { // Opening Brace on Same Line as if statement.
        // some execution;
    }
    // next statement not belonging to if statement;

    // Style 2: Concerning  else, if else, and if else else when using braces and indentation
    // Style 2a: Opening and closing block statement as well as conditions on separate lines.
    if ( condition ) 
    {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    } 
    else if ( some other condition )
    {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    }
    else
    {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    }

    // Style 2b: More compact
    if ( condition ) {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    } else if ( some other condition ) {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    } else {
        // Statement or statements of execution;
    }

    // These can be applied to nested loops as well.
    ```

I prefer the compact versions with the starting braces that defines a new scope for any of the following: namespace, class declaration, function definition, enumerations, switch statements and their case statements, if...else if... else statements, while and do while loops, for loops, and try and catch block statements. I prefer default tab or 4 white spaces for all indentation of all nested code block statements or new (nested scope). I prefer to keep my else if, and else's on the same line of the closing brace of the initial if statement so that I know it belongs to that code branch. Example

**MyStyle.cpp**

```
int main() {
    if ( condition || conditions ) {
        // Do Work;

     } else if ( some other condition || conditions ) {
        // Do This Instead;

     } else {
        // Otherwise; Finish with this;
     }

     // Nested If else if else
     if ( ... ) {
         if ( ... ) {
             // code;

         } else if ( ... ) {
             // code;

             if ( ... ) {
                 // code;
             } else {
                 // code;
             }

             // maybe more code;
         } else {
             // some other code;
         }
    } else if ( ... ) {
        if ( ... ) {
            // code;
        } 
        if ( ... ) {
            // code;
        }
        if ( ... ) {
            // code;
        } else {
            // code;
        }
    } else {
        // code;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The general idea about the style you choose should be: pick something that fits you, stick with that style as long as that style maintains readability and is kept simple in order for another reader or user to easily follow the code blocks or follow the style that your school, work or team uses.

As concerning your code with your conditions for your if statements consider this.

```
if ( 3 + 6 ) {
    // print 3+6;
} 

// The 3 + 6 either if using hard coded numbers or variable 
// is an expression and it will evaluate to some value. 
// Does this make sense to you?
if ( 9 ) {
    // do something;
}

// A constant value or variable, a constant expression will 
// always evaluate to true if used as a condition. 
// How can 9 every return false?

// If statements are designed to handle true or false conditions or comparisons.

// Boolean
bool imHappy = true;
if ( imHappy ) {
   // print( smiley face );
} else {
   // print ( frown );
}

// Or it could be written this way as well
if ( !imHappy ) {
      // print( frown );
} else {
      // print( smiley face );
}

// Logical Comparison 
const int adultAge = 18;
const int legalAge = 21;
int consumersAge = 0;

std::cout << "Can I see your ID?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> consumerAge; // Read of from DOB on ID

if ( consumerAge > 0 && consumerAge < adultAge ) {
    std::cout << "Sorry we can not do any of the following: \n"
              << "Sell you any tobacco products\n"  
              << "Serve you alcohol\n"
              << "Sell you lottery or allow you to gamble." << std::endl;
else if ( consumerAge >= adultAge && consumerAge < legalAge ) {
    std::cout << "Sorry we can not do any of the following: \n"
              << "Serve you Alcohol or Allow You To Gamble. \n"
              << "You are able to purchase: Tobacco and Lottery Tickets." << std::endl;
} else if ( consumerAge >= legalAge ) {
    std::cout << "You may purchase everything we sell and you are allowed to gamble." << std::endl;
} else {
     std::cout << "Invalid age entered: Are you even born yet?\n"
               << "You can not be " << consumerAge << " years old!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because each `else` statement (excluding your final block) has to be associated with an `if` block.  If you want to keep iterating through these options like you're trying, you need to change your code to this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number_1;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> number_1;

    int number_2;

    cout << "" << endl;
    cin >> number_2;

    int number_3 = number_1 + number_2;
    int number_4 = number_1 - number_2;
    int number_5 = number_1 * number_2;
    int number_6 = number_1 / number_2;

    if (number_1 + number_2) 
        cout << "" << number_3 << endl;
    else if (number_1 - number_2) 
        cout << "" << number_4 << endl;
    else if (number_1 * number_2) 
        cout << "" << number_5 << endl; 4
    else if (number_1 / number_2) 
        cout << "" << number_6 << endl;

    cout << "Press enter to continue" << endl;
    cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Making statements like the following are illegal in every language I know of:

```
if (/*some condition*/)
    /*do some action*/
else
{
    if (/*some condition*/)
        /*do some action*/
    else
        /*do some action*/
}
/*You're fine until right here...  The else is ALWAYS your last statement*/
/*It essentially says: "If we didn't meet ANY of our conditions, do this...*/
//Once you try doing this:
else
{
    //try doing something
}
//YOU MESSED UP
//We've already passed all the parameters we were testing
```

Just remember:  `if(/*some condition*/)` followed by as many `else if(/*some condition*/)`'s as you need, and **FINISH WITH** your `else` block.

### ALSO

It should be noted that you're not actually testing any conditions in your `if` statements - you're completing actions.  You **ABSOLUTELY HAVE TO** check a value of some kind (Boolean, numeric or otherwise...)  For example:

```
if (number_1 + number_2 != 0) 
    cout << "" << number_3 << endl;
else if (number_1 - number_2 != 0) 
    cout << "" << number_4 << endl;
else if (number_1 * number_2 != 0) 
    cout << "" << number_5 << endl; 4
else if (number_1 / number_2 != 0) 
    cout << "" << number_6 << endl;
else cout << "Invalid number." << endl;
```

Comment: ty guys sorry if it was off topic I am new here so I am trying to learn ty though

Comment: @NazgûlRiver Just make sure to vote on answers (_the up arrow and check mark_).  You'll figure out how this all works in due time.  We all started somewhere.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I need 15 reputation first I wish I could upvote you

Comment: Click the check under the up/down vote.  Accepting answers gives you points